# How can I combine C++ template template parameter deduction with perfect forwarding?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, c++20, type-deduction

Let's say I have a function that wants to deduce template template parameters to handle types that encapsulate other types, like `std::optional`:

```cpp
template <template <typename> typename M, typename T>
void Foo(const M<T>& input);

// Deduces M = std::optional, T = int
Foo(std::make_optional(0));
```

This is great, but it accepts the input only as an lvalue reference. What if I want to accept any sort of reference, and pass it through to `Bar` with perfect forwarding? Without the deduction of `M` this is easy:

```cpp
template <Input>
void Foo(Input&& input) {
  Bar(std::forward<Input>(input));
}
```

But now I've lost the deduction of `M`. **Is there any way to deduce `M` *and* get something as convenient as a forwarding reference?** I would like to avoid defining the function four to eight times if `Bar` needs to know the template `M`:

```cpp
template <template <typename> typename M, typename T>
void Foo(M<T>& input);
  Bar<M>(input);
}

template <template <typename> typename M, typename T>
void Foo(const M<T>& input);
  Bar<M>(input);
}

template <template <typename> typename M, typename T>
void Foo(M<T>&& input);
  Bar<M>(std::move(input));
}

template <template <typename> typename M, typename T>
void Foo(const M<T>&& input);
  Bar<M>(std::move(input));
}
```

Comment: That's definitely the same subject, thanks. It doesn't exactly answer the question of "is there a more elegant way to do this than overloading the function". I guess the answer is no?

Comment: I'm curious as to why you would need to do this. Generally, when you are forwarding a parameter to someone else, you don't need to interact with it in any meaningful way. That's kind of the point: you *don't care* what type it is; you just need to hand it to someone else. Once you need to care, it stops being forwarding.

Comment: This is for the sake of looking up a specialization of a struct that knows how to deal with the particular encapsulation. For example if I want to define an `Fmap` function that can map `std::optional<T>` to `std::optional<U>` but also `std::vector<T>` to `std::vector<U>`, and its implementation is essentially `return internal::FunctorOps<M>::Fmap(std::forward<???>(input))`, with the real intelligence in a hidden `FunctorOps` struct specialization.

Comment: "*but also `std::vector<T>` to `std::vector<U>`*" That's not possible; `vector` takes two template parameters, even if one of them can be defaulted.

Comment: Yes, sure, bad example. The point still applies; it should work for 1-element templates for which the struct is specialized.

Comment: Why not make it work for *types* for which the struct is specialized? Why do you specifically need them to be "1-element templates"?

Comment: The `FunctorOps` struct is about how to handle a specific type of functor, in Haskell's terminology (something like `std::optional`). For example how to implement `fmap` and `pure` for `std::optional`. Logically it's tied to `std::optional` in general, not `std::optional<T>` for a specific `T`. But you're right, I think I see how I could instead define it for `std::optional<T>` (at the cost of more template instantiation compiler CPU time) in particular and get what I want. Thanks!